# Are Brushes defined in WPF Style Setters instantiated every time the style is used?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Please consider the following xaml fragment:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.45"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="0.8"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Suppose the style is defined in an application-level resource dictionary. When a control references the style, does WPF instantiate a new instance of the `LinearGradientBrush` class every time? Or is there a single shared instance of `LinearGradientBrush` that is used?

I would like to know if it would be more efficient to define the `LinearGradientBrush` elsewhere, and then reference it in the Style as static resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one instance of that style and of its constituent objects.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure about the style being automatically frozen, though? It contradicts  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 "For convenience, freezable objects remain unfrozen unless you explicitly freeze them."

Comment: @Oliver: Indeed, seems to not be that way. Might have misremembered something that has bitten me once (I tried animating something that ended up being frozen implicitly, but I cannot remember all the details).